# Segfault when invlpg instruction is called

Tags: x86, segmentation-fault, tlb

I am trying to implement tlb flush function. For flushing I use `INVLPG` instruction, but unfortunately it always cause segmentation fault. Could you help me with this issue?

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"

inline void tlb_flush_entry(int *m) 
{
    asm volatile ("invlpg %0"::"m"(*m):"memory");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *memory = (int *)malloc(100);
    tlb_flush_entry(memory);
}
```

Comment: `invlpg` is a privileged instruction. It can only be executed from kernel-side code.

Comment: Thank you, I missed this in specification. What is then most natural way to flush tlb from user space (I need it for benchmarking purposes)? Develop kernel module?

Comment: @Alexander AFAIK You need to develop a kernel module for that.

Comment: I need the same function (for stress testing). Is there a kernel module that does this (invalidates the TLB cache) already and can be tickled from user mode?

Answer (score 1):

The SIGSEGV happens because INVLPG is a privileged instruction and can only be called out of kernel code.
This means you can't evict a userspace page out of the TLB that way.
However I wrote a litte kernel module demonstrating the usage of invlpg:
[How to use INVLPG on x86-64 architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752664/how-to-use-invlpg-on-x86-64-architecture/37754060#37754060)