# How to use INVLPG on x86-64 architecture?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, tlb

I'm trying to measure memory access timings and need to reduce the noise produced by TLB hits and misses

In order to clear a specific page out of the TLB I tried to use the INVLPG instruction, following those two examples: http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging and 
http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples

I wrote the following code:

```
static inline void __native_flush_tlb_single(unsigned long addr)
{
   asm volatile("invlpg (%0)" ::"r" (addr) : "memory");
}
```

But the resulting binary throws an SIGSEGV on execution.
As I prefere Intel syntax, I had a look at the particular disassembly:

```
invlpg BYTE PTR [rdi]
```

If I understand this correctly, invlpg will be called with the byte value at RDI, but would rather require a QWORD address.

However the second link says "The m pointer points to a logical address, not a physical or virtual one: an offset for your ds segment"

So INVLPG needs an offset from the ds segment? But the ds segment isn't used in AMD64 anymore, is it?

Can someone explain me how to use the INVLPG instruction with AMD64 or how to evict an TLB entry on this architecture?

Comment: The distinction between a virtual address and an offset from the data segment base is irrelevant on AMD64 since the data segment base is zero anyway. But I can't tell why this faults with this information. What did you put in there as address?

Comment: You are aware that this is a privileged instruction, right? It can only be executed from *kernel* code.

Comment: Oh good point, wasn't aware of that.. with that info I also found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253498/segfault-when-invlpg-instruction-is-called So I'm going to write a kernel module doing this job...

Comment: I don't really see why this is necessary. Unless I seriously misunderstand something, there is no point in invalidating a TLB entry that refers to a user-mode address. The kernel doesn't access user-mode address space, which is what you would presumably be passing to this function. If you just want to time memory-access or code or whatever, the way it's generally done is just to execute the code or query the memory enough times in a loop that you drown out the noise.

Answer (score 8):

The SIGSEGV happens because INVLPG is a privileged instruction and can only be called out of kernel code (Thanks [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)).

In order to demonstrate the use of INVLPG I wrote a little LKM *invlpg_mod.c* :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

// LICENSE
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static inline void invlpg(unsigned long addr) {
    asm volatile("invlpg (%0)" ::"r" (addr) : "memory");
}


// init module
static int __init module_load(void) {
    int mem;
    invlpg((unsigned long) &mem);
    printk("Evicted %p from TLB", &mem);
}


//unload modules
static void __exit module_unload(void) {
    printk("Goodbye.");
}

module_init(module_load);
module_exit(module_unload);
```

Make sure you have the linux-headers installed and build the LKM with this Makefile:

```
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)

obj-m = invlpg_mod.o

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Load the LKM with:

```
 sudo insmod invlpg_mod.ko
```

And unload it:

```
sudo rmmod invlpg_mod.ko
```

See the output:

```
dmesg | tail
```

Comment: You might also prefer to use the exported kernel wrappers around this instruction.. I believe some of them are exported to use with kmodules.